# Angular 5 Resolver to resolve Firebase request

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I am trying to use Angular's Resolver to load data to my component before initializing it.

```js
resolve() {
  return this.db.object("categories").valueChanges().subscribe(res => res)
}
```

The problem is since this is asynchronous I cannot access the data in time for the component to load. Is there a way to first wait for the first subscription data to arrive before returning the resolve with the required data?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to return an observable from the resolve method

```
resolve() {
    return this.db.object("categories").valueChanges();
}
```

And then subscribe to it inside the constructor or ngOnInit of your component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like the first batch of data from the subscription to be ready before I load the component.

Comment: Yeah thats what resolvers are for. Whats the problem now?

Comment: The resolver will return an observable right? But I want the actual object this observable returns, specifically the first one. Also, when I use the code you commented above, it does not get resolved at all, i.e my component does not load at all.

Comment: Do you get any error when the component doesn't load?

Comment: No error. It's as if the return statement of the resolver doesn't produce the correct result

Comment: You can try console.log(this.db.object("categories").valueChanges()). It should be an observable.